# Web Interface for Mass Changes to Database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, excel, asp.net-4.0

I'm working on an application that organizes large amounts of athletic statistics for universities. The client wants to be able to upload an Excel file to make updates to the database.

Example Excel Spreadsheet:

```
University | 2012 Men's Basketball Attendance | 2012 Out-of-State Tuition
Harvard    |                          100,000 |                  $100,000
UPenn      |                          150,000 |                   $90,000
UCLA       |                           60,000 |                   $40,000
```

I'm worried about correctly identifying the `UniversityID` and `StatisticID` because of row headers like "UPenn", "University of Pennsylvania", "Pennsylvania, University of" or column headers like "2012 Men's Basketball Attendance", "Mens Basketball Attendance 2012", etc...

I originally planned on having a grid of textboxes, but that isn't practical for them (they get stats from a whole bunch of reports in various formats for thousands of stats and hundreds of schools).

I'm thinking about allowing them to download an Excel file that would look something like this:

```
          StatID|                             1546 |                      7562
UID |University | 2012 Men's Basketball Attendance | 2012 Out-of-State Tuition
101 |Harvard    |                                  |                  
126 |UPenn      |                                  |                  
634 |UCLA       |                                  |
```

and just telling them not to mess with the row/column headers, and fill in whatever they want to change, but this still seems pretty risky (and is hardly `l33t`).

Anybody have any better ideas? I'm pretty much open to whatever.

I'm using ASP.Net 4.0, SQL Server 2008, jQuery 1.7.1, Excel 2010

(I'm ok telling them they have to use an up-to-date browser for this editing interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having them upload/download Excel spreadsheets with this: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm sorry that you didn't get a response to this thread before you found your answer, but one method I've used in the past to get around this problem is to prompt the user to identify unknown values by selecting from existing values (either distinct values from a column, or column names from a table). Then you can replace the errant values and process the spreadsheet normally.

Comment: thanks @Chris using EPPlus I was able to apply data validation and custom properties to workbooks when they are downloaded. I then created a datatable to with matching schema and added each row in the spreadsheet with a `Try Catch` block to throw an exception to tell the user which cell is causing an error. I then used `SQLBulkCopy` to pass it to the database.